Inset in Edit mode not showing in Object Mode
I am brand new to blender, I am following a tutorial on youtube - TipTup Basic Blender Toon / Cel Shader
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBztmFHkNQo&list=PLHoZH5RmmJe8Hu3W0XJ4vQtCGpgfWoKid
I am stuck at 3:28 when it goes to the part to inset the bottom and top face.
It shows the inset in Edit mode, but when I change to object mode it doesn't show the inset, versus how on the tutorial it does show it.
I have tried looking for solutions but none quite fit what I'm having. I attached screen shots to help see the issue.

The bottom is a flat face so you won't see the inset in Object mode because there's no change in face angle for light to bounce off and show the edge.  The tutorial doesn't show it so why are you expecting this to be a problem?

thank you, this was my first tutorial so I'm very new at this.

No problem. In Object mode and Rendered view you won't see any vertices or edges and you'll only be able to see where two faces join if they are at an angle to each other or are different colours.
